# Access an IP address using ssh

Tags: ssh

I have to connect to a server in another country. The person responsible provided me the IP address of the server and asked me if I could reach the that particular IP address through a regular access with ssh software?

What exactly should I do? How can I test this?

Comment: Move to Super User?

Comment: Well, obviously my rep would tell you that I am new in here. You guys could have just suggested that instead of giving me downvotes. .. anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Pavanred Indeed.  I'm voting to move this to superuser.com.  I'm thinking maybe some people don't know (or can't yet) vote to move someone to a different stackexchange site.

Comment: If you just need to check if the port is open, you can just telnet to port 22 (telnet x.x.x.x 22) --telnet is available on WinXP by default, for Win7 you'll need to install it from control panel> programs & Features>"turn windows features on" (install telnet client)

Comment: @Pavanred: you're not new in here, you've been a member for two months, and I think some of the negativity may be down to a complete absence of evidence of your having attempted to solve the problem yourself.  If you'd tried to google "windows ssh", PuTTY would have come up top (Simon Tatham, the author, is quite proud of PuTTY's extreme googlability, and uses it as justification for not having a custom domain name for the project (see the PuTTY FAQ, A.9.1)).  Honestly, your having made some effort to solve your problem first, and letting us know what it was, helps us all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mention cmd so I'm guessing this is a windows machine.  You need to install a program that supports ssh. Putty is a popular windows program that does.

From Putty's website:

> In really simple terms: you run PuTTY on a Windows machine, and tell it to connect to (for example) a Unix machine. PuTTY opens a window. Then, anything you type into that window is sent straight to the Unix machine, and everything the Unix machine sends back is displayed in the window. So you can work on the Unix machine as if you were sitting at its console, while actually sitting somewhere else.

[Putty download site](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty.exe)
[Putty documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/)

If that doesn't work check to see if a port is correctly forwarded.
Go to [You Get Signal](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) type in the ip address of the server and port 22 (the standard ssh port) and click check.

Answer (score 9):

Log on to your server and use the ssh command on your server to ssh to his computer.  For exmaple:

```
ssh 192.168.10.1
```

if it connects, then yes you can ssh to his IP address.

Comment: Is this a linux machine or a windows machine? That will help determine what software needs to be installed.

Comment: its a windows machine.

Comment: Follow JamesBarnett's advice on installing putty, then use that to connect to the IP address of the remote machine.

Comment: What are the options for linux machine?